# Issues with using/installing python solidity parser

Tags: solidity, python, parser, tools

I am trying to install and use [python solidity parser by ConsenSys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/python-solidity-parser)

I keep on getting the following error

`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/seed/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/python-solidity-parser/solidity_parser/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .parser import parse_file, parse, objectify, visit
  File "/home/seed/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/python-solidity-parser/solidity_parser/parser.py", line 10, in <module>
    from solidity_parser.solidity_antlr4.SolidityLexer import SolidityLexer
  File "/home/seed/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/python-solidity-parser/solidity_parser/solidity_antlr4/SolidityLexer.py", line 783, in <module>
    class SolidityLexer(Lexer):
NameError: name 'Lexer' is not defined`

Is there any other dependency that we are supposed to install that I missed?
I am running this on ubuntu with python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with trying to install it with pip3. It works if you build and install it manually (git clone and run setup.py).

Note that it links to another repo that does not get cloned so you have to clone that repo in the same folder again.